# Sinatra assets not loading on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, assets

I built a Sinatra website and pushed to Heroku, but somehow the CSS, JS and images from the public folders are not loading.

The site is here: https://teng-quora-k.herokuapp.com/

This is how it looks like locally:

[image: How the site looks locally]

Here is the `<head>` section

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/application.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>Teng-Quora-k</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/application.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here's the Gemfile, just in case

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Ruby Version
# ruby "2.2.1"

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib'
gem 'thin'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'shotgun'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'puma'
end

gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'
gem 'faker'
```

And this is in my procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you starting the server (both locally and on Heroku)? What options are you using for `shotgun` and in your `Procfile`?

Comment: (Note that `rails_12factor` won’t do anything, as this is a Sinatra app, not Rails.)

Comment: I use `shotgun config.ru` to run it on my local machine. I've added the procfile setting in my question above. I'm using a Sinatra template provided from someone else, and the `rails_12factor` gem was there initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to specifically define the public folder path in `config/init`, and it worked! Here is the path:

```
# Setup public folder
set :public_folder, File.join(APP_ROOT, "public")
```

Hope that somebody will find this useful one day :)